# Where can I find a reference where all RichFaces attributes of every component are explained?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

Especially rich:autocomplete. There are a lot of possible attributes but not all of them are explained, neither in the [Developers Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/appe-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters-richautocomplete) nor in the [Component Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_1_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs.html#sect-Component_Reference-Rich_inputs-richautocomplete). For example there is no information about fetchValue, immediate, selecteditemClass,...

Comment: what about [RichFaces Showcase](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=autocomplete&skin=ruby)? Also, `immediate` comes from JSF, it's not an invention in RichFaces

Comment: Showcase is good for examples but they explain much less the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the [Tag Library Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/). Here is the [`<rich:autocomplete>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/autocomplete.html).